# rvm on OS 10.9 a few problems: second export path to .bash_profile, missing 2.0 path, and missing files

Tags: ruby, bash, rvm

1)

I have this error every time I load a new bash terminal

```
-bash: /etc/profile.d/sm.sh: No such file or directory
-bash: /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh: No such file or directory
```

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16631326/error-message-bash-etc-profile-d-rvm-sh-no-such-file-or-directory) previously asked question with the answer to simply delete the references from .bashrc. But the answer is unaccepted and unvoted and the references to these files are not in .bashrc but in `~/etc/profile`

I should note that I don't have a profile.d directory under `/etc`. I have files `profile` and `profile~orig`

2)

RVM added a second `export path` after I ran `rvm get stable`, but did not include a reference to Ruby 2.0.0 in either.

```
.bash_profile

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/Users/mcb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin:/Users/mcb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/bin:/Users/mcb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin:/Users/mcb/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

My instinct is to combine them into one, eliminate repeats, and add the references to ruby 2 manually. I also added the `$PATH:` myself, since that didn't work the first time either.

3)

This is clearly not right

```
my-macbook-pro:~ mcb$ rvm get sable --auto-dotfiles
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/mcb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin' is not available,
         usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
         it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
         to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p247'.
cat: /Users/mcb/.rvm/help/get: No such file or directory
```

So, long story short I'm starting to get worried about trying to fix anything else myself without some sort of guidance for fear of just making things worse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for 1) check `/etc/profile` for those two files references

for 2) remove `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/Users/mcb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin:/Users/mcb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/bin:/Users/mcb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin:...` from `~/.bash_profile`

for 3) `rvm get sable` => `rvm get stable`

Comment: For 1, I have checked `/etc/profile`, those lines are there, can I just delete the references like the linked answer suggests?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are adding ruby 1.9.3 explicitly in your PATH, and that's a job that rvm shoud do.

In my case I have no direct reference to any of the ruby installations in my PATH.

Try cleaning your path from anything ruby and rvm related, and let rvm load as a function.
This is the .bash_profile on my computer (with rvm and brew working):

`export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*`

To check if rvm is correctly configured you can run:
`type rvm | head -n 1`

The result should be: "rvm is a function"

Checkout rvm official webpage for more details on how it works: https://rvm.io/rvm/install